# How to create grid inside a bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I am a beginner in HTML and CSS

And need to create such modal content: https://ibb.co/RvrhmRs

Most of the things are done for now my modal looks like https://ibb.co/1zG0y2t

Just need to arrange this icon beside the text.

I try with a different method like poisoning or using CSS but not set aspected

Can someone just give me an idea of HTML structure?

Your support is appreciate
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the flex property appropriately.

```css
.text-wrapper { 
  display: flex;
  }
```

```html
<div class="text-wrapper">
    <div class="text-wrapper-text">
        <div>Classes</div>
        <span>of goods and services</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text-wrapper-text">
        IMG
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works almost Now it looks like https://ibb.co/x7XVrkN can you please help me to align the above 2 to 3 text with below Classes section https://ibb.co/kg75gBZ

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to center the text below the number 8?

Comment: Means I need to align like this https://ibb.co/s9ShNZ5 you can see a red line here

Comment: Hard to say because I can't see your code. Make sure the parent of these elements has text-align: left. Or if you are using flex there, you might need to set justify-content: flex-start;
Another possibility is, maybe you have applied margin-left and margin-right to 'auto' and content is centered.